# How to access free SharePoint for personal learning and or just for refreshing memory for an interview?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

Is there any way I can access sharePoint for temporary usage OR for free test SP Capabilites ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start with a free 30-day trial, or buy an Office 365 Developer account (with one user license for either option). [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment)

Answer (score 1):

It's depend what you want learn, SharePoint power User skills or SharePoint Administrator (most on prem) skills.

For SharePoint online, you can use the trail of office 365 and explore many functionalities including the power user as well as Tenant Admin. You can use this link to signup for [O365 trail](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans)

Or if you want to learn On prem as power user then use [SharePoint hoster's](http://sharepointhoster.com/free-sharepoint-2013-hosting) free hosting( trail).

But if you want o learn the on-prem activities i.e installation, configuration, creation of service application etc then you have to install it on server using the SharePoint server 180 days trial. You need either a server product or configure a VM on your laptop to install and configure the SharePoint. [check this blog](http://www.thesharepointguide.com/sharepoint-2016-installation/)